# why doesn't this php foreach return the value?

Tags: php

If you look at the code below, it doesn't echo anything out when the `return` is in the `if` statement.  When I take the `return out`, it echoes out the correct value.  Why is this?

```
$images=  Array(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 131],
        [width] => 400]

     ),
   [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 140],
        [width] => 900]
     )
  )

  $array_key=0;
  foreach($images as $key => $image){                 
      if($image['id'] == $image_id){
         $array_key= $key;
         return;       
        }
   }             
  echo $array_key;
```

Comment: Usually not a good idea to have two variables of very similar names - like plurals - can lead to confusion.

Comment: `return` stops a function from further processing and returns the value or if used as `return;` returns `null`. `break` is for loops and breaks out of the loop and continues with the rest of the script. `continue` is for loops, it will stop the current processing item and go to the next item in the loop.

Comment: @MichalSkrzypecki but surely in my code above, it's not doing the assignment beforehand because at that point, `$array_key` has already been assigned to `$key`

Comment: `foreach` is a loop not a function. My comment was based on your questions below, where you asked for the difference between `return` and `break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `break` instead of return;

```
  $array_key=0;

  foreach($images as $key => $image){                 
     if($image['id'] == $image_id){
        $array_key= $key;
        break;       
     }
  }
```

From [php return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php):

If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call; If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended. If the current script file was included or required, then control is passed back to the calling file.

Comment: If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call; If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended. If the current script file was included or required, then control is passed back to the calling file

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code.

You need to add a **`break`** statement and the **`$image_id`** value has to be defined.

```
<?php
$images=  Array(
   0 => Array
       (
       'id' => 131,
        'width' => 400

     ),
   1 => Array
    (
    'id' => 140,
     'width' => 900
     )
  );

  $array_key=0;
  $image_id=140;
  foreach($images as $key => $image){
      if($image['id'] == $image_id){
          $array_key= $key;
          break;
          ///return;
      }
  }
echo $array_key;
```

Comment: whats the difference between break and return?

Comment: return cancels all further PHP parsing in the function.  break just ends the loop

Comment: return returns a value from a function. Break just comes out of a loop. We are breaking from a loop, since we found a match.